# NoMethodError in Doorkeeper::AuthorizationsController#new - Doorkeeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

I played around with doorkeeper using different flows. I tries successfully with password flow, client credential flow but with authorization code flow I got the following error:

```
NoMethodError in Doorkeeper::AuthorizationsController#new

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

When I clicked the authorize button as shown below: [image: click on Authorize button]

Error page:

[image]

Please help

Comment: I encountered similar error except that what I got is `undefined method `unshift' for nil:NilClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally it worked for me. The problem was because I did have the resource_owner_authenticator block to return a User object in config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb.

```
#config/initializers/doorkeeper.rb
resource_owner_authenticator do
  User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]) || redirect_to(login_url)
end

resource_owner_from_credentials do |routes|
  User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error until I realized you have to return the user from the resource_owner_authenticator block (which isn't obvious from the documentation).  My last line in the block did not return the user, which threw the error.